# NodeJS ReadStream not reading bufferSize bytes at a time

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer

I have a code where the NodeJS server reads a file and streams it to response, it looks like:

```
var fStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {'bufferSize': 128 * 1024});
fStream.pipe(response);
```

The issue is, Node reads the file exactly 40960 bytes a time. However, my app would be much more efficient (due to reasons not applicable to this question), if it reads 131072 (128 * 1024) bytes at a time.

Is there a way to force Node to read 128 * 1024 bytes at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new here, so bear with me....

I found this in node's sources:

```
var toRead = Math.min(pool.length - pool.used, ~~this.bufferSize);
```

and:

```
var kPoolSize = 40 * 1024;
```

So it seems that the buffer size is limited to 40kb, no matter what you provide. You could try to change the value in the code and rebuild node. That's probably not a very maintainable solution though...

Comment: This is right. I edited the value to 128 * 1024 and rebuilt the node. It still doesn't do the job, but its still better. It usually reads about 128000 bytes in one read, and then the remaining balance (128k -  ~128000) in the next read. Which is kinda strange.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is wrong. You can force Node to read *(128*1024)* bytes at a time using the **highWaterMark** option.

`var fStream = fs.createReadStream('/foo/bar', { highWaterMark: 128 * 1024 });`

The [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering) specifically states that *'the amount of data potentially buffered depends on the highWaterMark option passed into the streams constructor. For normal streams, the highWaterMark option specifies a total number of bytes. For streams operating in object mode, the highWaterMark specifies a total number of objects.'*

Also, see [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/523929c9272a53c9429616564a45f2af59670e47/lib/fs.js#L1461-L1463). The default buffer size is 64 KiloBytes